# How can I automate remote deployment in python?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, plumbum

I want to automate the remote deployment which currently I am doing manually.

The process includes

1. Make the tar ball from certain folders
2. SFTP to the remote server
3. Rename the old folders
4. Untar the new tar file
5. Restart apache

The remote system is on the intranet and has no access to the outside internet

I want to know how can I transfer the file from my python script and then when the transfer is complete then log into ssh and do stuff. I am confused about how can I achieve that. On localhost and I can do all that but how can I do that on a remote host?

Comment: Call a shell script using `system`, you can easily write a bash script to take care of that for you!

Comment: If it were me, I'd use `git` and the `post-receive` hook as in these examples: [1](http://www.sitepoint.com/one-click-app-deployment-server-side-git-hooks/) [2](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto). The idea is to push to a git repository on the server, and use a hook (a script) that copies the latest files to the deployment directory and does the restart, or signals a cron to do the restart. Actually most of your steps (tarballing, keeping old folders) may be irrelevant once git is managing the backups and revision history for you.

Comment: @Paul my problem is that on remote system , internet is not avaiable . only intranet. so thats why i want to get all stuff on my local computer and once ready then i can VPN

Comment: @KKJOJ That's important.  You should edit that into the question. git works over ssh, and you can have more than one git repository, e.g. have one on a gateway machine that sees both nets and pushes to the intranet machine.

Answer (score 0):

For simple&dirty work you can use [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) (This by no means say that you cannot use fabric to build serious product)

For heavy configuration routines, you'd better pick a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_management) (e.g., [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home))